# How to get an Array out of an Array which only contains only a special key

Tags: objective-c, arrays

I have an Array in XCode which has Locations in it and each location has properties like displayName, Category etc...

Now I want to filter that array so that I get an array which only contains locations out of the Category "XYZ" for example?

How do I do that in XCode?

My Locations array look like

```
{ 
[displayName: "Location1", category: "XYZ" ],
[displayName: "Location2", category: "ABC" ], 
[displayName: "Location3", category: "XYZ" ],
[displayName: "Location4", category: "ABC" ], 
[displayName: "Location5", category: "XYZ" ],
[displayName: "Location6", category: "ABC" ], 
}
```

Of theses 6 i want Location 1,3,5 for example in a new Array like this:

```
{ 
[displayName: "Location1", category: "XYZ" ],
[displayName: "Location3", category: "XYZ" ],
[displayName: "Location5", category: "XYZ" ],
}
```

Comment: Please provide some minimal sample code. We do not even know what the objects look like in your array.

Comment: What about searching about how to filter array, and maybe adding to it predicates or blocks? What have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this piece of code where mixedArray is your initial array and newArray is the filtered array, YourLocation is your location class.

```
NSArray *newArray = [mixedArray objectsAtIndexes:[mixedArray indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:^BOOL(YourLocation *location, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {

    return ([location.category isEqualToString:@"XYZ"]);
}]];
```

hope it will help you.